# How to correctly link the protobuf library to my cmake project that uses ExternalProject_Add for protobuf?

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I try to connect protobuf to my project using cmake (`target_include_directories`, `target_link_libraries`) after use `ExternalProject_Add(protobuf)`.

When I build solution in MSVC I get a lot of link errors.

One of them for example:

> ````
> symbol "struct absl::lts_20230125::from_chars_result __cdecl
> absl::lts_20230125::from_chars(char const *,char const *,double &,enum
> absl::lts_20230125::chars_format)"
> (?from_chars@lts_20230125@absl@@YA?AUfrom_chars_result@12@PEBD0AEANW4chars_format@12@@Z)
> referenced in function "double __cdecl
> google::protobuf::io::NoLocaleStrtod(char const *,char * *)"
> (?NoLocaleStrtod@io@protobuf@google@@YANPEBDPEAPEAD@Z) ```
> ````

Here is how I use `ExternalProject_Add`:

```
ExternalProject_Add(protobuf
  PREFIX protobuf
  SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../grpc/third_party/protobuf"
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
        -Dprotobuf_WITH_ZLIB:BOOL=OFF
        -Dprotobuf_ABSL_PROVIDER:STRING=module
        -Dutf8_range_DIR:STRING=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/utf8_range/lib/cmake/utf8_range
        -Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME:BOOL=OFF
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf
  DEPENDS utf8_range
)
```

That's how I add it to my project:

```
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} protobuf)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    debug ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf/lib/libprotobufd.lib
    optimized ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.lib
)
```

I don't know how to get rid of these errors (one of them):

> ```
> external symbol "private: void __cdecl
> absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessage::CopyToEncodedBuffer(class
> absl::lts_20230125::string_view,enum
> absl::lts_20230125::log_internal::LogMessage::StringType)"
> (?CopyToEncodedBuffer@LogMessage@log_internal@lts_20230125@absl@@AEAAXVstring_view@34@W4StringType@1234@@Z)
> ```

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? This would be much easier if you replace `ExternalProject` with `FetchContent`, but that requires at least CMake 3.11, but preferably CMake 3.14 or later.

Comment: If you insist on using `ExternalProject`, then you must use _two_ -- one for protobuf and one for your project. This is called a "super-build" setup. This is because protobuf isn't built until the actual build tool runs, i.e. too late for CMake to find the right files.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ExternalProject` is more trouble than it's worth 99% of the time (the other 1% is when you're building code generation tools that are specific to your build). The best way to consume an external dependency *by far* is to just use `find_package`. Then it doesn't matter how you or your users get `protobuf`, you can just use it. I'll show how to easily integrate this with `vcpkg`, which is probably the easiest way to get started on Windows.

I assume you're using the latest release of Visual Studio.

### Vcpkg setup

We will use vcpkg to manage building our dependencies. Follow the directions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/get_started/get-started?pivots=shell-cmd

From a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt:

```
> git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
> cd vcpkg
> .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat -disableMetrics
```

Then you can save this directory to your user environment:

```
> setx VCPKG_ROOT "%cd%"
```

Then restart your shell. You can optionally add the `VCPKG_ROOT` directory to your user `PATH` variable from the System Properties UI. Doing it from the command line is error-prone and overly complex.

### Project files

#### `person.proto`

This is just a dead-simple example Protobuf:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package example;

message Thing {
    required string name = 1;
}
```

#### `main.cpp`

This is just a simple application that should fail to build if Protobuf isn't being linked correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.pb.h"

int main()
{
    auto thing = example::Thing();
    thing.set_name("foo");
    std::cout << thing.DebugString();
    return 0;
}
```

Really nothing exciting here, it just prints a newly created `Thing`.

#### `vcpkg.json`

This is the file Vcpkg uses to determine which dependencies to install.

```
{
    "dependencies": [
        "protobuf"
    ]
}
```

#### `CMakePresets.json`

CMake presets are the modern way to inject optional, but convenient/common, sets of build settings. We don't want to force downstreams to use vcpkg (maybe they want to use Conan, or a system package manager), so we hook into vcpkg here.

Tools like Visual Studio Code, JetBrains CLion, Qt Creator, etc. all understand CMake presets these days.

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "vcpkg",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
            "toolchainFile": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### `CMakeLists.txt`

And finally here's the build. This is really all you should need to use protobuf.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(example)

# Find Protobuf - vcpkg will ensure this is found
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

# Create the executable target and attach our source files to it
add_executable(myapp main.cpp person.proto)

# Convert the .proto files to C++ sources/headers
protobuf_generate(TARGET myapp)

# Link to protobuf
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE protobuf::libprotobuf)

# Add the include path for person.pb.h 
# I wish protobuf_generate would do this for us, but alas...
target_include_directories(
    myapp PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>")
```

### Building from the command line

From a Developer Command Prompt, navigate to your project directory and simply run

```
> cmake --preset vcpkg
Preset CMake variables:

  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="C:\Users\alexr\dev\vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Running vcpkg install
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    protobuf:x64-windows@3.21.12#1
  * vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows@2023-05-04
  * vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows@2022-02-06#1
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Restored 3 package(s) from C:\Users\alexr\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 818 ms. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/3 vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows@2022-02-06#1...
Elapsed time to handle vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows: 3.1 ms
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows package ABI: 2403295b16a89617c9b370da7c0623fbd367f74d96073f18b118a706b76396f2
Installing 2/3 vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows@2023-05-04...
Elapsed time to handle vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows: 3.26 ms
vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows package ABI: 9b6155fee1061b05e9e6c60e34f0d671da02947e5247f9418fe73ed2e08e3ef9
Installing 3/3 protobuf:x64-windows@3.21.12#1...
Elapsed time to handle protobuf:x64-windows: 32.6 ms
protobuf:x64-windows package ABI: 3344512c7dec25fc60f1ebcee4f47f78ba19ab9dd7ddfe6456db79cf8e8184c4
Total install time: 39 ms
...
-- Running vcpkg install - done
...
-- Found Protobuf: optimized;C:/Users/alexr/dev/protobuf-example/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/libprotobuf.lib;debug;C:/Users/alexr/dev/protobuf-example/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/libprotobufd.lib (found version "3.21.12")
-- Configuring done (11.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/alexr/dev/protobuf-example/build
```

Then once `vcpkg` has built and installed `protobuf` into your build tree, you can run the following command to build it:

```
> cmake --build build --config Release
MSBuild version 17.4.1+9a89d02ff for .NET Framework
  1>Checking Build System
  1>Running cpp protocol buffer compiler on person.proto
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexr/dev/protobuf-example/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
  person.pb.cc
  Generating Code...
  myapp.vcxproj -> C:\Users\alexr\dev\protobuf-example\build\Release\myapp.exe
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/alexr/dev/protobuf-example/CMakeLists.txt
```

and we can see that it runs:

```
>.\build\Release\myapp.exe
name: "foo"
```